# Using Transition Matrix to Find General Solution to Nonhomogeneous System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transition-matrix

> Consider $v'=\begin{bmatrix}
>  0&1 \\ 
> -2 & 3
> \end{bmatrix}v+\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}$ with transition matrix of associated homogeneous system $\Phi(x,0)=\begin{bmatrix}
> 2\mathit{e}^{x}-\mathit{e}^{2x} &-\mathit{e}^{x}+\mathit{e}^{2x} \\ 
> 2\mathit{e}^{x}-2\mathit{e}^{2x} &-\mathit{e}^{x}+2\mathit{e}^{2x} 
> \end{bmatrix}$.  Find a general solution to the linear nonhomogeneous system with $v(0)=0$.

I already verified that $\Phi(x,0)$ is the transition matrix for the associated homogeneous system. Do I use the formula $\Phi(x,0)\mathbf{\xi}+\int_{\tau}^{t}\Phi(t,\eta)g(\eta)d\eta$ to the general solution to the linear nonhomogeneous system, where $\xi=0$, $\tau=0$, and $g(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$?

If I use that formula, how do I integrate the matrix? Any hints and ideas are greatly appreciated!

I get $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{bmatrix}+\int_{0}^{t}\Phi(t,\eta)\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}d\eta$, but I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: I used the first link and got $v=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathit{e}^{t}-1\\ 
\mathit{e}^{t}-1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!!!